# Mysql issue having 11 million rows of data

Tags: mysql

In my database having 11 million rows of data
any my sql query is

```
SELECT dgs.country_code COUNTRY_CODE
     , dtc.name COUNTRY
     , SUM(dgs.impressions) IMP
     , SUM(dgs.clicks) CLK
     , SUM(dgs.conversions) CON
     , FORMAT(((SUM(dgs.clicks)/SUM(dgs.impressions))*100),4) CTR 
  FROM djax_geographical_stats dgs 
  JOIN djax_conf_targ_country dtc 
    ON (dtc.value = dgs.country_code 
     OR dtc.iso_countycode_alpha3 = dgs.country) 
 WHERE 1 
   AND date_time BETWEEN '2020-07-22' AND '2020-08-20' 
 GROUP 
    BY dgs.country_code 
 ORDER 
    BY COUNTRY asc 
 LIMIT 10
```

it takes more than 60 seconds to execute

How to reduce the execution time

Comment: `OR` conditions are hard for MySQL to optimize. Split it into two queries that you combine with `UNION`.

Comment: Do you have indexes?

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using ?